Changing the collation of a SQL Server / Azure database
I have some test/prod databases in collation Latin1_General_CI_AS.
I have written a script to change one of the test databases for every char/nvarchar column in every table to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8
This is to handle chinese data and also to allow mixed case to be found in SQL queries
I know I could change database collation but this would require doing a bacpac and changing the collation in the bacpac and then doing an import on the bacpac - on a 500GB prod db this isnt really an option. Also I would need to make the database collation Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8 - the difference being CS as every object would become case sensitive and our application would need a complete rewrite for every SQL query / object etc.
So back to my problem above, can I keep the db in Latin1_General_CI_AS and just keep all existing and create new string columns as Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8.

The database collation is just the default collation... it won't change any existing columns, only new columns. Although it may cause issues with variables IIRC. But its not really clear what you are trying to do.

Thanks I think that answers my issue. All our new databases are setup as Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC_UTF8 with column collation set as Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8. This is done because if a column is saved as 'tree' - i only want to find it if the query uses the exact name of lowercase tree, otherwise CS will return results even if my query has TREE in it. The original question related to an old database that was set up before UTF8 was an option to use as collation and I wanted a clean way to change the columns as quick as possible with minimum downtime.

This smells like an XY Problem. If you change the columns to a UTF-8 collation, you should change the database too. Honestly, why not just use an nvarchar, without changing the collation? Otherwise you need to change the collation and change nvachar columns to varchar and change the database collation.

My rule of thumb is, if you're asking about utf8 in sql server, you don't know the pain of actually using it later, don't do it! What's wrong with nvarchar? Collation changes can be a pain too, especially if you have a lot of indexes, defaults and functions etc

Thanks, we are already using nvarchar on all our databases. The reason we chose UTF8 is because when we deployed a chinese version of our application we realised every piece of SQL would of needed an N in front of the statement so it would update/insert properly.  This collation suits all our databases even though i agree it has space increase issues.
